# How to detect and verify a renewal for an auto-renewable subscription?

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, storekit

So I have setup an auto-renewable subscription for my app with a period of 1 month, which equals 5 minutes or so in the sandbox. In the client app I subscribe, send the receipt to my server, it gets verified and I put a record in my database that this user has a subscription.

My question is how do I check if this subscription has been renewed? I have read the docs and can't figure out what should I do.

Here is where I am so far:

1. The initial receipt that gets sent to my server is verified with a status `0`, great. I also get `latest_receipt`, which I replace in my database with the oldest receipt.
2. After 6 minutes when I try to verify the `latest_receipt`, I get status `21006` (expired receipt) and this:

```
   { receipt: 
       { original_purchase_date_pst: '2013-08-06 11:58:04 America/Los_Angeles',
         unique_identifier: '------------',
         original_transaction_id: '----------',
         expires_date: '1376129825000',
         transaction_id: '------------',
         quantity: '1',
         product_id: 'subscription',
         item_id: '--------',
         bid: 'com.--------',
         unique_vendor_identifier: '---------',
         web_order_line_item_id: '---------',
         bvrs: '2.0',
         expires_date_formatted: '2013-08-10 10:17:05 Etc/GMT',
         purchase_date: '2013-08-10 10:12:05 Etc/GMT',
         purchase_date_ms: '1376129525000',
         expires_date_formatted_pst: '2013-08-10 03:17:05 America/Los_Angeles',
         purchase_date_pst: '2013-08-10 03:12:05 America/Los_Angeles',
         original_purchase_date: '2013-08-06 18:58:04 Etc/GMT',
         original_purchase_date_ms: '1375815484000' },
      latest_expired_receipt_info: 
       { original_purchase_date_pst: '2013-08-06 11:58:04 America/Los_Angeles',
         unique_identifier: '-------',
         original_transaction_id: '-',
         expires_date: '1376129825000',
         transaction_id: '-',
         quantity: '1',
         product_id: 'subscription',
         item_id: '-',
         bid: 'com.-',
         unique_vendor_identifier: '--',
         web_order_line_item_id: '-',
         bvrs: '2.0',
         expires_date_formatted: '2013-08-10 10:17:05 Etc/GMT',
         purchase_date: '2013-08-10 10:12:05 Etc/GMT',
         purchase_date_ms: '1376129525000',
         expires_date_formatted_pst: '2013-08-10 03:17:05 America/Los_Angeles',
         purchase_date_pst: '2013-08-10 03:12:05 America/Los_Angeles',
         original_purchase_date: '2013-08-06 18:58:04 Etc/GMT',
         original_purchase_date_ms: '1375815484000' },
      status: 21006 }
```

The second element in the array used to be `latest_receipt_info`, but now it's `latest_EXPIRED_receipt_info`. Here is what the docs say:

> In addition to the receipt_data field, the response may also include
>   two new fields. **If the user’s subscription is active and was
>   renewed** by a transaction that took place after the receipt your
>   server sent to the App Store, **the `latest_receipt` field includes a
>   base-64 encoded receipt for the last renewal for this subscription**.
>   **The decoded data for this new receipt is also provided in the
>   `latest_expired_receipt_info` field**. Your server can use this new
>   receipt to maintain a record of the most recent renewal.

So if the sub has been renewed since my server last checked, the decoded receipt for the renewal should be in **`latest_expired_receipt_info`**. In that object the `expires_date` is the same as the original receipt's `expires_date`.

What the hell? I just want to check if the sub is active. Can anyone explain in simple words how do I do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

My experience. Let's assume, we always send initial receipt to Apple's server.

In any case, you'll get JSON with at least two fields: `status` (no comments) and `receipt` (information about receipt that you've send).

Additionally to that:

1) If the subscription is *still active*, you'll additionally get `latest_receipt` (base64-encoded string) and `latest_receipt_info` (information about that receipt).

2) If the subscription is *already expired*, you'll additionally get `latest_expired_receipt_info` (information about last renewing receipt). Yes, you get only information about it, no base64-encoded string.

And yes, AFAIK, that's not documented anywhere. Hope that helps.

Comment: And the immediate question - why doesn't the sandbox auto-renew the subscription? Or how do I renew it myself? Right now the receipt expires after 5 minutes and that's all. I need to test my code somehow.

Comment: In sandbox, you are working with test accounts. You can't use test account to log in to iTunes and disable auto-renewing of your subscription. To let you test the situation, when your auto-renewable subscription becomes expired and inactive, Apple is doing only 5 renews in sandbox (i.e. you have initial transaction and 5 renews after it -> the total subscriptions queue' length is 6 times your subscription length).

This will refresh after 8 hours. Or you can use other test account.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. Here is a simpler explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033673/ios-sandbox-environment-auto-renewal-subscription

Comment: Basically, I just need to verify the initial receipt. That answers my question.

Comment: So in Sandbox, how do you get the receipt to expire?

Comment: @Cmag The subscription expires after a couple of automatic renewals, usually after 5 renewals. That way you can test both cases. Also note that the test subscription duration is way shorter than the actual duration: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/TestingInAppPurchases.html

Comment: @AlexandrPaliy I have a query what will happen to the main receipt when he cancels and activates the subscription again? Whether new receipt will be generated or what will happen?

Comment: Unbelievable how Apple has turned a simple subscription service to rocket science for developers!!

Comment: @NikolayDyankov
In sandbox test account auto-renewable subscription successfully excuted ( initial transaction and + 5 renews after it )
but after that i can not get latest_expired_receipt_info so how I can validate that auto-renewable subscription is expired 

In Response I get status,environment,receipt,latest_receipt,latest_receipt_info
I  did not get latest_expired_receipt_info

Comment: @AnkurPatel This answer is longer valid, since `latest_expired_receipt_info` is only for iOS6.

Comment: checking `latest_receipt_info ` instead ?