# iOS In-App Purchase Auto renewable subscriptions disabled by user

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscriptions, auto-renewing

I've been searching for this answer for quite a while, but it seems confused while I got different answers which is not yet solving my question. However, I couldn't test this situation through sandbox environment too...

The question is simple:
 While user disables the **auto-renewable** subscription, what is the result returns when validating receipt through https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt ?

(a) return status = 0, receipt is valid. You couldn't check whether user has disabled the auto subscription.

(b) return status = 21006, receipt is valid. This happen while the subscription reached expiration date? (I have no idea how this happen since I couldn't test this out)

(c) you'll have `latest_expired_receipt_info` if user disables the receipt. (This is what I found from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/18161118/3871220, but honestly, I can't have this field after my test account has reached limit(6 auto-renew purchases).

Therefore, I really need someone who has experience with this, gives me a clue and I would be appreciate that very much!