# In App purchase Auto renewable Subscription iOs

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase, auto-renewing, shared-secret

I am implementing In App Purchase and using Auto renewable Subscription type product, for the first time It is working fine. For other then first attempt I am getting 21004 in reciept's  status (21004 showing error related to shared secret key )
How can i perform the test of this condition that application will correctly work 
i.e, product is renewing after correct renewal days.?
and how to solve the problem of getting a ststus 21004?

Thanks

Comment: The durations for subscriptions in the sandbox are greatly reduced to a matter of minutes to allow you to test the renewal process. See here for a list of durations http://stackoverflow.com/a/14711190/241138  as for the error, are you verifying receipts from the app or from your own server? I assume you're supplying your secret when verifying receipts?

Comment: you just have to add password = "secret key" in json parameter just refer below link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14976453/im-getting-21004-as-status-value-in-reply-from-apples-sandbox-server-testing-a

Comment: This link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680059/auto-renewable-subscription-in-ios7/45220204#45220204
might help you.